# Problem while sorting DataTable with LINQ based on DateTime

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I want to sort a DataTable based on a column which has date value. I was running in to issues so i created following test method:

```
private static void Test()
    {
        DateTime testDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2011");

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("dateValue");
        table.Columns.Add("slNo");

        DataRow row1 = table.NewRow();
        row1["dateValue"] = "01/01/2011";
        row1["slNo"] = "1";

        DataRow row2 = table.NewRow();
        row2["dateValue"] = "01/02/2011";
        row2["slNo"] = "1";
        DataRow row3 = table.NewRow();
        row3["dateValue"] = "02/01/2011";
        row3["slNo"] = "1";
        DataRow row4 = table.NewRow();
        row4["dateValue"] = "01/03/2011";
        row4["slNo"] = "1";

        table.Rows.Add(row1);
        table.Rows.Add(row2);
        table.Rows.Add(row3);
        table.Rows.Add(row4);

        var t = table.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<DateTime?>("dateValue")).ToList();
    }
```

I get Following error:

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

The date provided can be parsed to DateTime object. But still it get the above error. Any idea what is missing?

I use C# 3.5

Comment: is your DateTime field a nullable type in your DataTable?

Comment: Yes it is nullable. But even if i make it non-nullable in the above method it won't work..

Comment: infact you didn't have a DateTime field.You just had a string field which you were trying to cast it to DateTime.

Comment: @Ashley John: As long as it is a valid DateTime string there should not be any error while parsing rite... Basically it is some legacy code which i want to sort.. otherwise i would not have used a DataTable in the first place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the following line:

```
table.Columns.Add("dateValue");
```

to this:

```
table.Columns.Add("dateValue", typeof(DateTime?));
```

Comment: Throws: DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>. for me.

Comment: typeof(DateTime?) won't work but defining the column with typeof(DateTime) did the work. Thanks BFree.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the ToList() in last line it works.

var t = table.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field("dateValue")).ToList();

It appears the cast problem happens in the call ToList();

Comment: That's just because IEnumerable is lazy and the collection doesn't get enumerated. As soon as you'll do a foreach over the t variable, it'll blow up...

Comment: Exactly.. @BFree it will throw while you do a  forEach

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the column type, so try to use object in the Field:

`var t = table.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<DateTime?>("object")).ToList();`

Comment: This won't serve the purpose rite.. we want to do sorting based on daveValue Field..

Comment: oops, it should be: var a = table.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<Object>("dateValue")).ToList();